# Admob wants 640,100 Has: 480,654 - why is no 480 size banner delivered?

Tags: android, admob, space, banner

I'm running my Admob android app on a Galaxy S2 Emulator with screen dimension 480x800px.
Admob gives the error:

```
"Not enough space to show ad! Wants <640,100>, Has <480,654>"
```

Why wants admob deliver a 640 banner and not a 480 banner instead? How can I fix that?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no banner in admob with size 480 but the closed banner size is 468 x 60

to change the needed banner size log into your admob account and:
sites & apps => below mediation (tabhead) configure

link to doc:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate

Answer (score 0):

AdMob's AdView uses density independent pixels. If you request a 320x50dp banner on a device with 2.0 screen density, the pixel size will actually be (320x50)*2 = 640x100.

The Galaxy S2 is a hdpi device with density 1.5 (so AdMob would request a 480x75). It's possible you misconfigured the emulator to have a 2.0 screen density, so there isn't actually enough space to show the ad in portrait mode.